# Bar chart + geom_jitter with the points of the jitter inside the fills of the bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I would like to have a bar chart with the distribution of the population I am studying, this bar chart has age as x axis (count is y) and the filling is ethnicity. I'd like to overlay some of the subjects inside their corresponding groups with a geom_scatter. However it creates its own axes.
I can't share the data but here's a dummy tibble

```r
df = tribble(
  ~id, ~agegroup, ~ethnicity,
  #--|--|----
  "a", "20s", "African Descent",
  "b", "30s", "White",
  "c", "50s", "White",
  "d", "40s", "Hispanic",
  "e", "20s", "White",
  "f", "30s", "Hispanic",
  "g", "20s", "Hispanic",
  "h", "30s", "White",
  "i", "20s", "African Descent",
  "j", "30s", "White",
  "k", "50s", "White",
  "l", "20s", "White",
  "m", "30s", "Hispanic",
  "n", "20s", "Hispanic",
  "o", "30s", "White",
  
)
df
dmplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = agegroup, fill = ethnicity )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "count")+
  labs(
    x = "Age Group",
    y = paste0("Population (total = ", df %>% nrow(), ")"))+
  geom_jitter(df,
              aes(x = agegroup,
                  y = ethnicity)) # this is where I would need to retrieve the geom_bar fill location
dmplot
```

Comment: Please share example data and your existing code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I added the tibble and my ggplot code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but I think something like this would do it. unfortunately it seems like you cannot assign jitter height to the aestetics, but you might be able to find another way to make height dependent on the height of the rect.

```r
df = tribble(
  ~id, ~agegroup, ~ethnicity,
  #--|--|----
  "a", "20s", "African Descent",
  "b", "30s", "White",
  "c", "50s", "White",
  "d", "40s", "Hispanic",
  "e", "20s", "White",
  "f", "30s", "Hispanic",
  "g", "20s", "Hispanic",
  "h", "30s", "White",
  "i", "20s", "African Descent",
  "j", "30s", "White",
  "k", "50s", "White",
  "l", "20s", "White",
  "m", "30s", "Hispanic",
  "n", "20s", "Hispanic",
  "o", "30s", "White",
  
)
df_2 <- df %>%
  count(agegroup, ethnicity) %>%
  group_by(agegroup ) %>%
  mutate(top_rect = cumsum(n),
         bottom_rect = lag(top_rect, default = 0))

df_2_uncounted <- df_2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  uncount(n)


ggplot(df_2) +
  geom_rect( aes(xmin = as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)) - .45,
                 xmax=  as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)) + .45,
                 ymin = bottom_rect, 
                 ymax = top_rect,
                 fill = ethnicity )) +
  geom_jitter(data = df_2_uncounted,
              aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)),
                  y = (bottom_rect + top_rect)/2),
              width = .3,
              height = .5) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(as.numeric(as.factor(df_2$agegroup))), 
                     labels = levels(as.factor(df_2$agegroup))) + 
  labs(
    x = "Age Group",
    y = paste0("Population (total = ", df_2_uncounted %>% nrow(), ")"))
```

[image]

### Update

now with labels

```
df_2_uncounted <- df_2 %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  uncount(n)%>%
  arrange(agegroup, ethnicity) %>%
  group_by(agegroup, ethnicity) %>%
  mutate(id2 = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(df %>%
              arrange(agegroup, ethnicity) %>%
              group_by(agegroup, ethnicity) %>%
              mutate(id2 = 1:n()),
            by = c("agegroup", "ethnicity", "id2"))


ggplot(df_2) +
  geom_rect( aes(xmin = as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)) - .45,
                 xmax=  as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)) + .45,
                 ymin = bottom_rect, 
                 ymax = top_rect,
                 fill = ethnicity )) +
  geom_jitter(data = df_2_uncounted,
              aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)),
                  y = (bottom_rect + top_rect)/2),
              position = position_jitter(seed = 1, height =0.5)) +
  geom_text(data = df_2_uncounted,
            aes(x = as.numeric(as.factor(agegroup)),
                y = (bottom_rect + top_rect)/2,
                label = id),
            position = position_jitter(seed = 1, height =0.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(as.numeric(as.factor(df_2$agegroup))), 
                     labels = levels(as.factor(df_2$agegroup))) + 
  labs(
    x = "Age Group",
    y = paste0("Population (total = ", df_2_uncounted %>% nrow(), ")"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time and effort, it works great but I had the idea to do something similar with boxplots and it would be better if there was an easier solution. Maybe I should go for a solution involving d3.js directly but it's quite the effort (d3 is hard lol).
In the meantime I'll use this thanks a lot !!

Comment: For boxlplots, this is actually really easy to implement: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/89-box-and-scatter-plot-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: Hi, follow up question, I'd like to keep the ids can I do this with your process ?

Comment: yes. please see update :). again a bit hacky for sure, but it works

Comment: Thanks a lot its perfect, I managed to adapt it to my data structure, it's great. Thanks again ! Have a great week !